# iOS NSCalendar Crash - References issue?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, release, retain, nscalendar

I'm seeing a number of crashes, all with slightly different manifestations, but they're all pointing to the same line of code, and I have a hunch but it's a bit outside my comfort-zone so I'd like some help.

The crash is related to NSCalendar's components:fromDate.

In the class in question there's an instance variable for an NSCalendar, and in my init method I call

```
calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
```

Later I call:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:myComponents fromDate:myDate];
```

The above line is where the crash occurs, and when looking at the crash logs I see a combination of errors for this one line:

- EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
- [__NSCFNumber components:fromDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
- NSInvalidArgumentException [__NSDate components:fromDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
- SIGABRT ABORT

I've checked and I'm not changing the calendar variable anywhere other than the initial creation of it inside the init method. As I said I do not modify the calendar variable anywhere in the code and I've not been able to replicate any of the other issues, but I've replicated the second crash by doing something like the following:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = @5;
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:myComponents fromDate:myDate];
```

Could this be some sort of memory reference issue? I've seen similar issues reported on SO posts from a few years ago pre-ARC (I've never done anything without ARC sadly), where people weren't properly retaining their variables. Could this be some sort of issue where the instance variable isn't properly retained, leaved the memory in a bad state causing these weird and seemingly distinct issues but all in the same place? Any and all information is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I will add that this is a rare/intermittent crash reported by crashlytics that I haven't been able to replicate to debug locally more than once, which is what leads me to believe it's either a memory management issue or perhaps a threading issue.

**SECOND EDIT:** I was looking back through some screenshots/log stuff I had back from the one time I was able to catch this issue in Xcode and I think I missed something.

If I set a breakpoint at that line, and print the calendar object:

```
po calendar
0x14d50a20
```

If I normally do a po on a brand new [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] I get:

> Auto-updating Calendar  [<_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x10922ae80>]

Does that mean that in the case where it was just an address the object was lost as I originally expected?

Comment: I can't tell what you're doing, but those crashes are because you are attempting to call the method 'components:...' On an NSNumber and then on an NSDate. I don't understand why you are setting the calendar to @5 which means you are setting it as an NSNumber.

Comment: If you log calendar just before the troublesome line, what does it give you.

Comment: You are using `components` in the method which you initialize `components` with. So on the right side `components` is uninitialized.

Comment: @CHBuckingham the code where I set the calendar to @5 is simply to replicate the crash. As I said, I do not alter calendar at any point after I create it.

Comment: @rdelmar I cannot replicate this crash locally, it is only being reported via Crashlytics. It has never personally crashed for me while in development and thus the calendar object always seems to be valid. This is a low-frequency crash.

Comment: @HAS I only put 'components' and 'date' in as placeholders for the sake of the discussion, they are not actually the variable names I'm using.

Comment: It does "smell" like your NSCalendar object is being lost, due to some sort of retain (weak/strong) issue.  It would help to know how/where `calendar` is being declared.

Comment: You can, of course, sidestep the issue by extracting `calendar` immediately before each use of it.

Comment: @HotLicks I mentioned in the original question that it is created inside the class' init and I call calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

Comment: @HotLicks Also, what do you mean by 'extracting' in this case? Create a new instance each time? In this case, performance is critical and from what I've read creating NSCalendar is relatively expensive.

Comment: @HotLicks see the most recent edit I just made, I think it might be a clue.

Comment: Yes, the info in your "second edit" suggests that either the NSCalendar object went "poof" (eg, due to a reference counting issue) or your `calendar` variable was "stepped on" (for reasons unknown).  Again, it would be helpful to know more about where and how `calendar` is declared.

Comment: @HotLicks Inside of the header file: interface MyObject : NSObject { NSCalendar *calendar;}

Comment: @HotLicks does the above comment give any enlightening information? Is there any way to determine if the object "went poof" as you say? I have a feeling it's not as easy as testing if it's nil, is it?

Comment: It's a difficult problem to crack.  I was working on something similar (but not identical) today and *I think* it was due to some UI accesses that were not done from the main thread.  But you never can tell for sure if the problem went away, of course.

Comment: Any comment on threading? I don't think `NSCalendar` is thread-safe. I can't immediately prove it but will check, hastily.

Comment: @Tommy it is not thread safe - that is definitely a possibility.

Comment: Indeed, and I've found the evidence: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html — check underneath 'Thread-Unsafe Classes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Ritu hit on this, there's more to it worth mentioning. I'm still not sure if this was a memory issue, a threading issue, or a combination of both (very possible) but getting rid of the instance variable and accessing the autoupdatingCurrentCalendar directly each time I need to solved the issue. This is because calling [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] returns a *unique instance* each time, which I wouldn't initially have thought.

Thus, getting rid of the NSCalendar instance variable and replacing each call to that variable with a call to get the autoupdatingCurrentCalendar would solve any issues accessing the same reference from multiple threads as well as if the object would have otherwise been corrupted, lost, released, etc., for any reason.

Comment: If you're supporting iOS 6 though, those `NSCalendar`factory calls can be unintuitively expensive. I was using `currentCalendar` rather than the automatically updating one and found that, under 6, sticking a copy in the thread dictionary cut something like 10% from the display time for a small table of things with a date calculation related to them. No difference under 7; Apple appears to have addressed the problem.

Comment: Fortunately, I'm only supporting iOS7, but that is definitely good to know!

Answer (score -2):

You should use:

```
     NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
     NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```